# Why the git command failing

Tags: git

I have a git repository on a linux server and same repository folder is synced to my Mac using Unison. When I run following command on Linux, I see the changed files.

```
git -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false status --porcelain -z --untracked-files=no -- .
```

When I run the same command on my Mac inside the repository, I get following error.

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I have checked the repository and it has the .git folder, so I'm clueless what the problem here. I have tried installing git from multiple sources but same problem. Looks like there is some problem within my git repo but how can I debug this?

I have other git repository which I sync using Unison and I don't see this issue. This issue only happens for only one repo.

Comment: What do you mean by *synced to [the] Mac* - if it's Dropbox, or a shared folder in VirtualBox, or various other sharing systems, none of those are reliable with Git.

Comment: Did you clone the repo in the same way that you cloned it on your linux box? The command should run fine on macOS, it runs and outputs correctly on macOS for me.

Comment: I'm using Unison to sync the repo. I have other repos which work perfectly, but git fails for one specific repo.

Comment: You should **not** sync your dvcs repositories with anything but the dvcs software itself. Any file synchronization utility won't keep the integrity of the whole repository in sync and you risk mixing and matching changes from multiple computers in one repository. **Don't do it!**

Comment: That's the most insidious bit about sharing software vs Git: it *sometimes* works, and then it fails mysteriously. When it fails it can destroy your repository!

Comment: I had to do that because the repository is not accessible from Mac and I want to do development on Mac. Mac's file system is not case sensitive which might be messing up the .git folder. I've been using this setup for years for another repo without any problem but that is synching to a partition on my Mac which is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Generally that means that you no `.git` folder in that directory you're in. When you "sync" your folder it's possible that files starting with a dot aren't replicated because they are hidden. So you should "clone" the repo on your mac. Then it should work.

Comment: I checked the repo which is synced (I'm using Unison for this) to my Mac and I can see the .git folder inside it.

Comment: But have you made a new clone? Syncing make Really no sense when you use git

Answer (score 0):

You say the `.git` dir is present, so it's most likely been damaged in some way by the Unison copy. Try checking permissions or comparing the `.git` directory contents.

However, in all honesty using Unison on a `.git` dir probably is going to keep breaking. Unison will effectively merge the `.git` dirs most likely producing something that is invalid.

I would embrace git's decentralised nature and make a new clone on OS X. You can even clone directly from the Linux checkout (as opposed to cloning from the origin of the Linux checkout) if that makes things easier.

This may lead to a lot of temporary commits, that only exist for the purpose of syncing code between your machines. Don't worry about this, you can always squash the commits later to tidy things up before you push your tidied commits to the upstream origin.

Comment: I have gone down this path but after sometime it's just too much work. For a single line change I have to commit on Mac and checkout on my Linux machine and build it.